# ImageView onClickListener on Android Api 5.0 not working

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-5.0-lollipop, onclicklistener

I have set an OnclickListener to an ImageView and when clicks performs an asyncTask, it works well on devices running below Api 5.0, but do not work at all in Android Api 5.0 devices.

Async Task:

```
public class SendName extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/web.php");

            String user = "John";

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);


                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));

                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   httpclient.execute(httppost);


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lengthOfFile) {

    }

}
```

ImageView XML:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/send"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:src="@drawable/send" />
```

OnClickListener:

```
ImageView send_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send);
send_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new sendName().execute()

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new SendName().execute()`?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace too. Looks like your using the legacy `HttpClient` that could be the problem.  Did you declare `useLibrary` in your gradle?

Comment: @JBirdVegas Am not using AndroidStudio

Comment: Is there a stacktrace? The legacy library must be included explicitly. You can do this through gradle or maven, not sure how the same can be accomplished in eclipse... Maybe include the legacy client's jar in the `libs` folder

Comment: did you declare imagview in onCreate method?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug the code if it goes inside the doInBackground or not.
If it runs then their might be some problem with HttpClient which is deprecated in Android 6.
You can first check and confirm if this is HttpClient problem, if it is then add following line in your app gradle

```
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

or you can also change and implement HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 0):

Put the following attribute in your XML inside image view

android:clickable="true"